# NullPointerException in reading gsp template

Tags: grails, groovy

Below is method for gsp template parsing that  have created:

```
String renderGSPTemplate(String templateText, Map bindings){
        def output = new StringWriter()
        String pageName = bindings.remove('pageName')
        groovyPagesTemplateEngine.clearPageCache()
        Template template1 = groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(templateText, pageName)
        Writable data = template1.make(bindings)
        data.writeTo(output)
        return output
    }
```

Below is exception that I am getting:

```
 Error java.lang.NullPointerException
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageOutputStack.lookupStack(GroovyPageOutputStack.java:102)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageOutputStack.currentStack(GroovyPageOutputStack.java:76)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.initRun(GroovyPage.java:213)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.doWriteTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:199)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.writeTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:128)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Writable$writeTo.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
| Error     at com.verecloud.nimbus4.mail.TemplateParserService$$EPpsYO6i.renderGSPTemplate(TemplateParserService.groovy:37)
```

Any one knows the reason for this error.

Thanks!

Comment: please tell me which line is line 37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groovyPagesTemplateEngine uses HttpRequest and hence if we are not having a call from web application it will fail with NullPointerException.

Hence it was failing for me with NPE